# Assign a single page in your own name using Route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

That's how I try to build such a "company" to their "own" front page. That is, you have a company called "Test", so it should appear in the url

If the other company is called "HelloWorld" then it should be so.

What is my problem here:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route(CompanyInfo.RouteCompanyName())]
public ActionResult Index()
```

In my method, I try to retrieve the company name of the single user profile that has been assigned.

```
public static string RouteCompanyName()
    {
        using (var db = new VagtSystemEntities())
        {
            var userid = UsersClass.Userid();

            var companynameInfo = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.UserId == userid);
            if (companynameInfo != null)
            {
                return companynameInfo.CompanyName.Name;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

If I let it be just called "index" then there are no problems.

Comment: That's the way attributes work. Google *dynamic route names mvc asp.net* and you may find some alternatives to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Thanks @TimMedora Good day to u